# preloading external swf files with actionscript as2

Tags: flash, external, preloader, actionscript-2

i'm relatively new with flash, so...

i've been looking into this for 2 days now, 
so i hope someone can help me out.

i have several external swf files, each one can 
call any of them.

say i'm in **home.swf** and i clicked **about.swf**, i 
want to stay in **home.swf** whilst **about.swf is being 

loaded** so i don't have an empty screen. they are 
**both external swf** files, hold by a main container.

my actionscript is in 2.0 and i know it has something 
to do with **"onLoadComplete"** before 
**"loadMovie ("about.swf", "_root.content");"** 
but i just don't know how to write this bit of code.

please please help me!!!! i really appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

If can help you have look to this site, it have a complete tutorial step by step to get the same result of your case.

[Click here to see a full tutorial](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/P-flash/T-How-to-load-an-external-movie-into-Flash/ID-5/)